# Не билдится образ в Docker под Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Установил Docker для Windows, авторизовался. Скачал Imaje:

```
docker pull openjdk:11-jdk-buster
```

Скачал по ссылке взятой от сюда https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat?tab=description&page=1&name=alpine
(отсюда же брал и имя образа) Dockerfile и попытался создать образ на основании загруженного образа и Dockerfile-а:

```
docker build . --tag openjdk_11_tomcat_9_0_39
```

На что он мне выдал ошибку, что имя файла не корректно, имя директории не корректно или значение описания не корректно. Привожу снимок ошибки - из консоли скопипастить не получилось
[image: Ошибка построения образа]

[image: Расположение файла]

Сам Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-buster

ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p "$CATALINA_HOME"
WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME

# let "Tomcat Native" live somewhere isolated
ENV TOMCAT_NATIVE_LIBDIR $CATALINA_HOME/native-jni-lib
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:}$TOMCAT_NATIVE_LIBDIR

# see https://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-$TOMCAT_MAJOR/KEYS
# see also "update.sh" (https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/master/update.sh)
ENV GPG_KEYS 05AB33110949707C93A279E3D3EFE6B686867BA6 07E48665A34DCAFAE522E5E6266191C37C037D42 47309207D818FFD8DCD3F83F1931D684307A10A5 541FBE7D8F78B25E055DDEE13C370389288584E7 61B832AC2F1C5A90F0F9B00A1C506407564C17A3 79F7026C690BAA50B92CD8B66A3AD3F4F22C4FED 9BA44C2621385CB966EBA586F72C284D731FABEE A27677289986DB50844682F8ACB77FC2E86E29AC A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7 DCFD35E0BF8CA7344752DE8B6FB21E8933C60243 F3A04C595DB5B6A5F1ECA43E3B7BBB100D811BBE F7DA48BB64BCB84ECBA7EE6935CD23C10D498E23

ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR 9
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION 9.0.39
ENV TOMCAT_SHA512 307ca646bac267e529fb0862278f7133fe80813f0af64a44aed949f4c7a9a98aeb9bd7f08b087645b40c6fefdd3a7fe519e4858a3dbf0a19c38c53704f92b575

RUN set -eux; \
    \
    savedAptMark="$(apt-mark showmanual)"; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        gnupg dirmngr \
        wget ca-certificates \
    ; \
    \
    ddist() { \
        local f="$1"; shift; \
        local distFile="$1"; shift; \
        local mvnFile="${1:-}"; \
        local success=; \
        local distUrl=; \
        for distUrl in \
# https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/INFRA-8753?focusedCommentId=14735394#comment-14735394
            "https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?action=download&filename=$distFile" \
# if the version is outdated (or we're grabbing the .asc file), we might have to pull from the dist/archive :/
            "https://www-us.apache.org/dist/$distFile" \
            "https://www.apache.org/dist/$distFile" \
            "https://archive.apache.org/dist/$distFile" \
# if all else fails, let's try Maven (https://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg134940.html; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat; https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/)
            ${mvnFile:+"https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/$mvnFile"} \
        ; do \
            if wget -O "$f" "$distUrl" --progress=dot:giga && [ -s "$f" ]; then \
                success=1; \
                break; \
            fi; \
        done; \
        [ -n "$success" ]; \
    }; \
    \
    ddist 'tomcat.tar.gz' "tomcat/tomcat-$TOMCAT_MAJOR/v$TOMCAT_VERSION/bin/apache-tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz" "$TOMCAT_VERSION/tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz"; \
    echo "$TOMCAT_SHA512 *tomcat.tar.gz" | sha512sum --strict --check -; \
    ddist 'tomcat.tar.gz.asc' "tomcat/tomcat-$TOMCAT_MAJOR/v$TOMCAT_VERSION/bin/apache-tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz.asc" "$TOMCAT_VERSION/tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz.asc"; \
    export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    for key in $GPG_KEYS; do \
        gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; \
    done; \
    gpg --batch --verify tomcat.tar.gz.asc tomcat.tar.gz; \
    tar -xf tomcat.tar.gz --strip-components=1; \
    rm bin/*.bat; \
    rm tomcat.tar.gz*; \
    command -v gpgconf && gpgconf --kill all || :; \
    rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME"; \
    \
# https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/security-howto.html#Default_web_applications
    mv webapps webapps.dist; \
    mkdir webapps; \
# we don't delete them completely because they're frankly a pain to get back for users who do want them, and they're generally tiny (~7MB)
    \
    nativeBuildDir="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    tar -xf bin/tomcat-native.tar.gz -C "$nativeBuildDir" --strip-components=1; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        dpkg-dev \
        gcc \
        libapr1-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        make \
    ; \
    ( \
        export CATALINA_HOME="$PWD"; \
        cd "$nativeBuildDir/native"; \
        gnuArch="$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)"; \
        aprConfig="$(command -v apr-1-config)"; \
        ./configure \
            --build="$gnuArch" \
            --libdir="$TOMCAT_NATIVE_LIBDIR" \
            --prefix="$CATALINA_HOME" \
            --with-apr="$aprConfig" \
            --with-java-home="$JAVA_HOME" \
            --with-ssl=yes; \
        make -j "$(nproc)"; \
        make install; \
    ); \
    rm -rf "$nativeBuildDir"; \
    rm bin/tomcat-native.tar.gz; \
    \
# reset apt-mark's "manual" list so that "purge --auto-remove" will remove all build dependencies
    apt-mark auto '.*' > /dev/null; \
    [ -z "$savedAptMark" ] || apt-mark manual $savedAptMark > /dev/null; \
    find "$TOMCAT_NATIVE_LIBDIR" -type f -executable -exec ldd '{}' ';' \
        | awk '/=>/ { print $(NF-1) }' \
        | xargs -rt readlink -e \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -rt dpkg-query --search \
        | cut -d: -f1 \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -r apt-mark manual \
    ; \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    \
# sh removes env vars it doesn't support (ones with periods)
# https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/issues/77
    find ./bin/ -name '*.sh' -exec sed -ri 's|^#!/bin/sh$|#!/usr/bin/env bash|' '{}' +; \
    \
# fix permissions (especially for running as non-root)
# https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/issues/35
    chmod -R +rX .; \
    chmod 777 logs temp work; \
    \
# smoke test
    catalina.sh version

# verify Tomcat Native is working properly
RUN set -eux; \
    nativeLines="$(catalina.sh configtest 2>&1)"; \
    nativeLines="$(echo "$nativeLines" | grep 'Apache Tomcat Native')"; \
    nativeLines="$(echo "$nativeLines" | sort -u)"; \
    if ! echo "$nativeLines" | grep -E 'INFO: Loaded( APR based)? Apache Tomcat Native library' >&2; then \
        echo >&2 "$nativeLines"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
    
COPY E:\Authorization_service_prjct\authorizationService\target\authorizationService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war : /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Docker только начал изучать.
Не пойму в где ошибка и как её исправить?

Возникли подозрения, что возможно что-то с загруженным образом не всё в порядке - проверил - запускается, в нем можно работать, всё нормально[image: Проверка образа]

Comment: Проверил загруженный образ - запускается и работает нормально (дополнил вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

Дело в символе переноса строки - в Windows это "CRLF", а в Linux - "LF".
Необходимо менять "CRLF" на "LF", если Dockerfile создан под Windows! Это можно сделать с помощью текстового редактора, н-р Notepad++, или другого.

Ошибка, которую выдает Docker при этой проблеме не информативна - об этом писалось и на некоторых форумах.

После того как указал ссылку на github с Dockerfile вместо ссылки на директорию хоста - все прошло нормально:

```
docker build https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat.git --tag name
```

До этого указывал на папку моего хоста (Windows), где лежал файл, который был создан копированием текста и содержал "CRLF" вместо "LF".